# testing react-redux with jest, actions may have undefined type property error

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

so testing a redux connecting container, I have multiple dispatch calls within. Most work fine, however, the action that returns types with array like so:

```
export const submitTest = () => ({
  [TEST_SUBMIT]: {
    types: [TEST_REQUEST, TEST_SUCCESS, TEST_ERROR],
  },
})
```

where it is being calling like **dispatch(submitTest())** in my component.

will error in jest with: **Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. You may have misspelled an action type string constant.**

Ultimately, the action uses a middleware that TEST_SUBMIT will equal '@@TEST_SUBMIT' and create an axios call to an endpoint.

Below is my jest test-utils for example set up (not mocking) and can assume all the correct imports:

```
const render = (
  component,
  {
    initialState,
    store = createStore(appReducer, initialState)
  }
) => {
  return rtlRender(
    component, {
    wrapper: TestWrapper(store)
  },
    { container: document.body }
  )
}

// eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
const TestWrapper = (store) => ({ children }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
  </Provider>
)

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react'

// override render method
export { render }
```

Comment: The error message is correct. It's not a proper redux action if `type` is missing. It looks like your action is meant for a specific middleware. You're currently not including any middleware in your test-store setup.

Comment: you were correct, I managed to import my middlewares from store file and add it to test-utils create store like so: store = createStore(appReducer, initialState, compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware)))